# python in conda uses packages in the user directory instead of those in virtual environments

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and using anaconda 22.9.0. I installed two versions of pytorch in my user directory and the conda virtual environment, respectively. Despite `which python` and `which pip` showing:

```bash
(openmmlab) user@hostname:~/Applications/anaconda3$ which python
/home/user/Applications/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/bin/python
(openmmlab) user@hostname:~/Applications/anaconda3$ which pip
/home/user/Applications/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/bin/pip
```

importing a package in python still shows it's using the one in my user directory `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, instead of in the conda environment directory `/home/user/Applications/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages` (I can confirm both packages exist). How should I solve it?

Additional information if it helps:

- I am trying to use 2 different versions of pytorch
- pytorch in my user directory was installed by `pip`, while the one in conda was installed using `conda install` while the environment was activated.

Comment: may it be related to your IDE settings ?